# Is a physicist a specialist, an expert or both?

Tags: word-usage

I am aware the definitions of "specialist" and "expert" on dictionary.

> [specialist](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/specialist)
>
> someone who has a lot of experience, knowledge, or skill in a
>   particular subject
>
> [expert](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expert)
>
> a person with a high level of knowledge or skill relating to a
>   particular subject or activity

However, I don't really understand the usage of them. For instance, is a physicist

> a specialist
>
> an expert

or both?

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: They could be both. _Expert_ emphasises a person's high degree of knowledge or experience in a subject, _specialist_ emphasises that they have concentrated on a particular narrow field of expertise.

Comment: I agree, and a physicist could be neither. They might be a generalist in the subject of physics. Both terms, "specialist" and "expert" are relative, not absolute.

Answer (score 2):

An expert is someone who knows a lot about a certain topic. A specialist is someone who has dedicated themselves to studying a topic.

The words have slightly different connotations. For example, J.R.R. Tolkien was a specialist in Germanic philology, but he was an expert in many other fields of knowledge such as the Finnish and Welsh languages, ancient European folklore, and creative writing.